# Avoid command injection with system() api

Tags: linux, c

We have a legacy C code used to allow less privileged user to run custom scripts with escalated privilege. This has SUID bit set. This code restricts the PATH env to a specific folder and then uses `system()` api to execute the script with restricted shell :

```
/bin/bash -r -c "script <arg>"
```

As the path is restricted, it can execute only scripts from that specific folder.

Now knowing all the pitfalls for command injection with `system()` api, what measures can be taken to avoid command injection? This is used in many places in various scripts etc, so don't want to do a completely new implementation to avoid any regression.

Comment: Whit the lack of data you present this question, the only sound advice we can provide is avoiding abusing suid. Otherwise, we cannot guess what your script does.

Comment: An application that does not filter input has to be modified to filter input, no way to get around it with magical Unix solutions.

Comment: As others have warned, it's easy to make mistakes in your own suid code. What about LD_PRELOAD and LD_LIBRARY_PATH, for example?

Comment: Are you sure you need system (which runs a command in a shell) instead of exec (which runs a command)? Often it can be more useful and secure not to use system, even when losing some flexibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because its hard to get right, I'd suggest removing the SUID on your code. Change your C code to use `sudo`. By using sudo the harder aspects getting secure system programming are done.

Then you can carefully construct a sudo configuration, using visudo, that does the bare minimum required to perform the task and constrain this to the required users/groups. After configuring sudo, get someone other than you to test it and try to break the intended constrains.

Comment: I do agree with not abusing SUID. However, sudo does neither corrects automagically layer 7 problems, nor is a magical bullet to sloppy coding pratices. I actually find your answer just giving a dangerous sense of security.

Comment: happy to make changes. General premise is that sudo is better audited than code you write yourself. I think its easier to write sudoers config files correctly than code that calls `system` and is suid. I agree mistakes still can be made. I'll reword so it doesn't sound so flippant.

Comment: I am not saying it is entirely a bad idea, do not get me wrong. It just it is not enough to make it automatically secure. An application that does not filter input has to be modified to filter input, no way to get around it with magical Unix solutions. The OP is expecting a miracle that won't happen.

Comment: @danblack I think this would work except that I may not know all the user names upfront. Let me see if I can find a way to map all these users to few groups and sudo policy accordingly.

Comment: Scripts in the restricted folders are properly validating and sanitizing the input. The issue that I was trying to address is, avoiding injection to what is passed to `system()` call. With sudo conf changes, I can change the code from `/bin/bash -r -c <name-of-restricted-script> <arg>` to - `/bin/sudo -u admin <path-to-restricted-script> <arg>`.  Even if some one inject a command/script, it would either be executed with the original user permission or won't execute at all depending on permission of that script/command.

Comment: I don't quite understand what issue this approach can solve. If `script <arg>` is vulnerable when called as `script magic_string`, how is running it with `sudo` safer compared to running it via SUID?

Answer (score 2):

Code injection requires the ability of the user to pass arbitrary strings as parameters to the `system()` call. This is pretty similar to SQL injections and should be avoided in a similar way: don't pass any user-defined string directly to the call:

- numerical parameters should be converted to integers, and then converted back to strings at the time of the call
- parameters which belong to a fixed dictionary should be converted to "enum" values or similar, then back to strings at the time of the call
- free text input should be restricted to inoffensive character set where possible (e.g. `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`). Where problematic characters (including space) are required, proper escaping should be applied (that is, `a b` should be replaced by `a\ b`, etc.)

Comment: backslash should be avoided for quoting as its encoding is part of some characters in some locale. Only single quotes are relatively safe. Note system() runs sh and the OP seems to want to run bash on top of that, so there may need to be two levels of quoting. Some sh implementations drop privileges when run setuid, so it may not work anyway. In any case, the environment would have to be sanitized as well.

Comment: DOn't forget to also run these checks on environment variables, and check all of them, not only `PATH`, also add a whitelist

Comment: @Ferrybig, the only reasonable approach for the environment is to start with an empty one, and white list the ones that have harmless names and values and that may be needed like sudo does. Even then, there's harm that can be done with all the `LC*` ones or `TZ` for instance.